# Reyclerview populating data only after edtitext above is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am facing an issue. The recyclerview is having data but it is populated only when the edittext above that is clicked and keyboard is opened.
Please guide me.  I think something is wrong with views.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/friends"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:hint="Search"
    />


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list_friends"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: can you give us more information? How is the recyclerview being populated? What is the code what does the edittext do? are they connected in any way?

Comment: Can you post the code? hehe

Comment: Actually its an autocompletetextview above recyclerview. Getting data from firebase and populating both recyclerview and autocompletetextview. Data is coming there but it is not shown until i click on the above autocompletetextview and the keyboard opens. Edited my question to add the xml file.

Comment: @JamesRusso lucas please have a look at it

Comment: this is just the XML, can you also post the java code you are using? or is there none that touches this two views?